# TensorFlow Probability: How to get accuracy of a prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm coding a TensorFlow model in this way:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(max_words,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_split=0.1)
```

I have this method that returns the prediction class of input:

```
def predict(input):
    try:
        q = model.predict(np.array([x_train[int(dict[input])],]))
        predicted_label = text_labels[np.argmax(q)]
        print("Classe Predetta: " + predicted_label + "\n")

        return predicted_label

    except:
        return "error"
```

Now I use softmax to obtain level of accuracy but this isn't the better way. I know that I can use probabilistic model with the new TensorFlow Probability.
I'd like to see code to know to get model and accuracy
Thanks

Comment: Are the results of `model.evaluate()` insufficient? If, by 'get model' you mean print the model layout, perhaps `model.summary()`